# Firebird dynamic Var New and Old

Tags: triggers, firebird, psql

I need validate dynamic Fields from a Table. For example:

```
CREATE TRIGGER BU_TPROYECTOS FOR TPROYECTOS
  BEFORE UPDATE AS
  DECLARE VARIABLE vCAMPO VARCHAR(64);
BEGIN
  /*In then table "TCAMPOS" are the fields to validate*/
  for Select CAMPO from TCAMPOS where TABLA = TPROYECTOS and ACTUALIZA = 'V' into :vCAMPO do
    Begin
      if (New.:vCAMPO <> Old.:vCampo) then
      /*How i get dynamic New.Field1, New.Field2 on query return*/
    End;   
END ;
```

The question is : How can I put "The name of the field that the query returns me " in the above code .

Ie if the query returns me the field1 and field5 , I would put the trigger

```
 if ( New.Field1 < > Old.Field1 ) or ( New.Field5 < > Old.Field5 ) then
```

Comment: You should work on your question. I'm not sure on whether it really is a question. Explain what you want to do, please.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Тhe variables have no old and new values. They have only one value at the moment. You can declare "old_vcampo" and "new_vcampo" variables and work with them.

Comment: Why do you want to check fields data change for another table (`TCAMPOS`) in the trigger of this table `TPROYECTOS`? The Old/New-thing is only available in a trigger for the table it was created for.

Comment: Explaining a bit more . In a " table1 " I have the names of the fields which I validate whether the value in the " table2 " is change.

For this in a "Before Insert trigger of table2" would do this.

The point is: I do not want the " old.value " of variable. That is : If the variable returns the value " name field1 " then I validate if there were changes in the " field1 name " field and that I want to do in the trigger of the " table2 "

Do I explained ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such feature in Firebird. You will need to create (and preferably) generate triggers that will reference all fields hard coded. If the underlying table changes or the requirements for validation, you will need to recreate the trigger to take the added or removed fields into account.